# How to set class based on current route name/controller

Tags: routes, angularjs

Trying to set a class based on my current controller or current route (URL Segment 1).

something like

```
<body class="{{controllerName}}">
```

That way in case I need to target separate pages for CSS specificity, it makes it easy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My solution would be: subscribe to route changes at route scope and put name of the controller there:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(ev,data) {   
     if (data.$route && data.$route.controller)
       $rootScope.controller = data.$route.controller;
   })
});
```

Check [Plunker solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/fR6gSqeXbROl410tgzPJ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! Made some slight edits as data.$route.controller was changing based on some tab controllers I had initiated. Just need the parent controller.

Comment: it's data.$$route.controller in 1.0.7

Comment: Note that properties starting with [$$ prefix are considered private](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) and are accessed or modified at your own risc (since they might change between versions of AngularJS).

Comment: Any idea why data.$route would be undefined? Valentyn, I have placed your code in my main Angular file, where routeProvider is also configured. routeChangeSuccess _is_ being fired.

Comment: if you use ui-router, I think it should be data.$$route instead of data.$route I guess

Comment: @NicolaMarcacciRossi still here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) service, it has `current` property which will give you current controller.

Comment: This is not available in `.run()` .

Comment: Could you please provide working example? I can not access $route.current from my controller :(

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler. There's a `controller` property directly on the `data` argument.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(e, data) {
    $rootScope.controller = data.controller;
});
```

As best as I can tell, the `data` argument is the same object as `$route.current`. The `controller` property is in the prototype for that object.

Answer (score 2):

For the version 1.3 of Angular, you can use this piece of code :

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (ev, data) {
    if (data.$$route && data.$$route.controller)
        $rootScope.controller = data.$$route.controller;
});
```

Comment: Using $$ properties is not recommended, as they are internal to Angular, not part of the public API, and are likely to be changed or broken in future updates.

From the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#-prefix-naming-convention): "If you inspect a Scope, you may also notice some properties that begin with $$. These properties are considered private, and should not be accessed or modified."