# Disable ng-include style inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to load a view through `ng-include` in angular.

The problem is that the nested view, inheritance some style from the parent view; is it possible to disable this functionality and use the inflated view freshly without any style inheritance?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes to some extent. You just need to write your styles properly to avoid conflicts.

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than Angular / updated tags

Comment: @dfsq I define the styles in the included view, but it's still has some conflicts with parent view and inheritance some of its style like fonts or paragraph style.
The odd is that, even if I define body style in the included view, it also has affected on the parent view!

Comment: @DanielA.White An iframe isn't a good solution for this. Use CSS specificity rules.

Comment: can use `scoped` styles for browsers that support it

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm agree about `iframe` but unfortunately, it has not support angular's scopes.

Comment: @charlietfl Any example?

Comment: @iSun This may help, but you'll need to "namespace" your global CSS to not have children inherit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220244/how-to-set-class-based-on-current-route-name-controller

Comment: see scoped example in mdn docs  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: @charlietfl Very great feature but unfortunately, not supported in `WebKit`.

Comment: This is a question of CSS specificity. You need to write your styles in a way that avoid any conflicts. It's possible to write styles that would not be affected by other styles no matter where you put them.

Comment: I found that the best solution for this kind of issues is that you can wrap your styles in some selector (class) and that styles will work only if you have your html elements inside that wrapper with that classname. That can be handled very easily if you are using LESS or SCSS.